# Sublime Text - how to figure out internal command name for key binding?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'd like to bind a shortcut key to `Edit > Tag > Wrap Selection with Tag`. How do I figure out the command name so I can put that into the user key bindings?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) to open the console, then enter

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

to turn on command logging. Go through the menus and click your target, and

```
command: insert_snippet {"name": "Packages/XML/long-tag.sublime-snippet"}
```

comes up. Enter the following into your `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User` file:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+w"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/XML/long-tag.sublime-snippet" } }
```

(changing the key combo if you wish) and you should be all set. Once you're done, go back to the console and enter

```
sublime.log_commands(False)
```

to turn off logging of every single action.

Comment: thanks! `sublime.log_commands(True)` has been incredibly useful for me, both as a plugin writer and just for customizing key bindings, etc.

Comment: Wicked!! Thanks! You win because you explain how I can use `log_commands` to find out any command from the menus.

Comment: Really need this (sublime.log_commands(True)) for Visual Studio Code. 
 Anyone know if it exists / how to get it working?

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo! `sublime.log_commands(True)` work for me to figure out **JSON Reindent** package command.

Answer (score -1):

Goto `Preferences > Key Bindings - Default` then search for `alt+shift+w` and you'll find the following, on line 566 for me:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+w"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/XML/long-tag.sublime-snippet" } },
```

You can change the `["alt+shift+w"]` to whatever you'd like. I'd suggest making this a new entry in `Preferences > Key Bindings - User` so you don't overwrite the defaults file.